# BufferedReader reads only once

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I'm tryin to read a configuration file and a strings file. The configuration file will be used to determine if the content in the string file is correct.

I created a package named StringAcceptor, part of the code is as follows:

```
    public static boolean isAccepted(File config, File lines_file, String string) throws Exception {

    //BufferedReader para obtener las líneas del archivo
    conf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(config));
    //BufferedReader para determinar la cantidad de líneas en el archivo
    lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lines_file));

    //Validación de archivo de configuración del AFD

    while(lines.ready()){
        lines.readLine();
        line_number = line_number + 1;
    }

    while(conf.ready()){
        try{
```

Here I start reading lines and assigning the values to the corresponding variables

Then I created a java file to use the package and send information to my StringAcceptor to determine if the string is accepted or not. The code from the class that uses the package is as follows. After importing the needed package and determining the option it excecutes either of this options:

```
                    case 1:
                            System.out.print("\nInsert configuration file name: ");
                            path = br.readLine();
                            archivo = new File(path);
                            if(archivo.isFile()){
                                System.out.print("\nInsert string to be verified: ");
                                String string = br.readLine();
                                if(StringAcceptor.isAccepted(archivo, archivo, string)){
                                    System.out.println("\nAccepted!\n");
                                } else{
                                    System.out.println("\nNot accepted.\n");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("\nFile does not exist.\n");
                            }
                            break;
                    case 2:
                            System.out.print("\nInsert configuration file name: ");
                            path = br.readLine();
                            archivo = new File(path);
                            if(archivo.isFile()){
                                System.out.print("\nInsert name of string file to be verified: ");
                                String string = br.readLine();
                                strings = new File(string);
                                if(strings.isFile()){
                                    BufferedReader sfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strings));
                                    while(sfile.ready()){
                                        if(StringAcceptor.isAccepted(archivo, archivo, sfile.readLine())){
                                            System.out.println("\nAccepted!\n");
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("\nNot Accepted.\n");
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else{
                                    System.out.println("\nFile does not exist.\n");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("\nFile does not exist.\n");
                            }
                            //archivo.delete();
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            exit = true;
                            break;
                    default:
                            System.out.println("\nInvalid Option.\n");
```

Whenever I excecute my code it will the following menu:

1) Verify String
2) Verify String File
3) Exit
Insert option:

Now, no matter what option I pick first or which configuration file I use first, it will only excecute correctly the first time, everytime after that it won't go inside the `while(conf.ready())` conditional, will never read the lines and will always return `false`because of it.

Hope my edit made it more understandable.

Comment: Good work but can you provide smaller example? Just enough to show your point. Not cut&paste whole application.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ - Short, Self Contained, Correct example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out where I was totally messing up. I was so focused on the file I was reading I was sure that was the problem. Problem turned out to be that I was not initializing to 0 some of the `int`"control variables" I was using for a few of my `for` cycles, so I ended up reading more than I was supposed to in each `for` because I kept adding to the last value of the variable (Curious it didn't show me an Exception for this).

Still, thanks everyone for your help, if I hadn't changed my code with your suggestions I never would've found out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the `ready()` tests. It is not valid to use that as a test for end of stream. That's not what it's for. See the Javadoc. Just read until `readLine()` returns null:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: Thing is that the .txt file must have a specific number of lines, and each line is assigned to a different variable, and by using the method you suggested I can no longer read the line that has already been read for the while. On the other hand, I can't do a while with a control variable to read a specified number of lines cause I need to be able to detect if the specific lines have a certain format, line by line.

Comment: OK so don't use a loop at all, just read the individual lines. But make sure they aren't null, i.e. that the file isn't truncated prematurely. Why are you counting those lines at the beginning?

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but for some reason it still doesn't work. I even added a `close()` method to the BufferedReader before every return statement. Still, only reads the configuration file the first time it executes.

Comment: You're going to have to explain that. What part of the code does it skip? Where does the skip start? You said before 'it won't go inside the `while(conf.ready())` conditional': well, now you've removed that, so it must. Are you ignoring an exception somewhere? or not telling us about it?

Comment: That's actually a good question. I had a try/catch statement, so I removed it to see if it would give me any Exception during execution, it turns out it does read the first 2 lines and then just stops for some reason. Trying to figure it out now.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove `ready` method. While reading with `BufferedReader` use `readLine` method to check if the data is available and then proceed.

Also while you are reading the files, I don't see code to close the streams. For e.g. below statement opens files for reading

```
BufferedReader sfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strings));
```

but where is the call to `sfile.close()`. Similarly, the isAccepted method is also opening file streams and not at all closing it.

You should better use

1. Try with resources (if using Java 7+)
2. Try/Finally

Comment: All true but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I didn't add those specific parts of the code, but I am using Try/Finally in pretty every needed part of my code (reading the file, reading numbers, etc). And I do have the conf.close() and sfile.close() in the code, still doesn't work.

Comment: But not fixed it. 'Read data from stream and check if it's not null' only applies to `readLine(),` not to any general way of reading the stream. And that paragraph is the only part that answers the question, so it isn't 'additional' at all. It should be first, and the *rest* of it is 'additional'.

Comment: @EJP you seems to have problem in interpreting what I am saying. Can't help with that.